# Python - Look in list for a item containing numbers

Tags: python, regex, list

```
some_list = ['Name','Surname','R500']

some_list = ['Name','Surname','500']
```

how would if get the index of the item in the list that contains a number, in both cases I should get back index = 2

I was looking at something like:

```
some_list.index(r'%r' % '\d+')
```

Answer (score 6):

You'll need to loop over the elements:

```
for i, x in enumerate(my_list):
    if re.search(r"\d", x):
        print i
```

Answer (score 5):

If you're looking just for the first item containing a digit, this works without regular expressions and returns `-1` (can be changed to whatever you want) if there is no element with digits:

```
next((i for i,n in enumerate(some_list) if any(c.isdigit() for c in n)), -1)
```